# Sendgrid powershell report for multiple subusers

Tags: powershell, api, reporting, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

So i`m trying to export all blocks for a subuser account in sendgrid, for which i have the following code

```
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiKey
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    'on-behalf-of'  = 'ACCOUNT-NAME'
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/blocks' -Headers $headers
```

Which works as expected, the thing is that I have around 30 subusers for which I need these details.

How can I do the `foreach` loop so I can get the data for all of them?

Thanks :)

Comment: How are these 30 account names stored?

Comment: I have used Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/subusers' to get a list.

Comment: it containst a table with status,email,id and username

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the hardcoded account name with whatever variable name you choose for the `foreach` loop variable, and the appropriate property name:

```
$users = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/subusers'

foreach($user in $users){
  $headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiKey
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    'on-behalf-of'  = $user.username       # here we grab the username from the current $user
  }

  Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/blocks' -Headers $headers
}
```

Comment: Now i get this ...

Comment: removeEmptyDebugTableEntries()
At line:4 char:3
+   Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'api.sendgrid.com/v3/subusers'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: @af3 I copied the first command from your comment above you probably need to add `https://` in front of the URL

Comment: indeed :) I added it but it also requires a header for the first GET so it can take the user list

Comment: therefore the code is now `  $mainheader = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiKey
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    }


  
  Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/subusers' -Headers $mainheader

foreach($user in $users){
  $headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiKey
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    'on-behalf-of'  = $user.username       # here we grab the username from the current $user
  }

  Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/blocks' -Headers $headers
}
`

Comment: it works but i get a ton of data now :)) ... any change that it could be filtered for the previous day only ? :))